# Lemma in Farkas/Kra: Riemann surfaces on construction of domain satisfying certain properties

Tags: general-topology, riemann-surfaces, harmonic-functions

[image]

I'm having some trouble understanding the proof of this lemma. I can follow the construction of $u$ and $D$, however the final step in the proof seems to be without justification. Specifically why does $D$ satisfy (3.1.2) and (3.1.3)? It's obvious from the construction that it's satisfies (3.1.1).

Comment: Google book links are a bad idea. They do not always work because Google restricts what pages you can view. I suggest putting the text that you are asking about into the body of your question.

Comment: I'll edit in a picture.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that the preimage of a regular value of a smooth function from a surface to the real line is a smooth 1-dimensional submanifold?

Comment: Ah. That makes it quite simple then. Don't think I had seen that before though, my exposure to differential geometry's been a bit patchy. Thanks.